# Descriptive declarative kernel language

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology, theory, language-design

In this question I reference Van Roys and Seif Haridi book - **"Concepts, techniques, and models of Computer Programming"**.

Background information(interpreted by my own words from the referenced book):

> Declarative program defines what we want to achieve without explaining
>   how to achieve a certain result. A declarative program may be
>   Descriptive or Programmable

---

> The Programmable level describes the component(context and behavior)

---

- I would like others to explain to me what is the *descriptive declarative* program and what does it define?
- I would also like to mark the relation(difference) between the *descriptive* and *programmable* levels in **practice(programming languages)**

This question arose while reading the referenced **book**, a chapter about declarative programming. (Page 115 tells about classifications of declarative programming, where descriptive declarativeness definition is a little unclear, at least for me)

Answer (score 2):

A descriptive declarative Oz program is a program that only uses variables and values. It does not use any control structures or recursion. For example:

```
A = 42
```

or

```
B = person(name:"Hans" age:20)
```

or even (creating a "infinite" record):

```
C = loop(data:42 link:C)
```

An HTML document (without using any extensions like embedded Javascript) would also be a descriptive declarative program.
A purely descriptive language is not Turing-complete.
Purely descriptive programs are a real subset of programmable declarative programs.

A programmable declarative program can contain recursion and many other control elements. The model is described in chapter 2 of the book. An important property is "referential transparency", i.e. no  matter in what situation or how often you call a function, it will always return the same result given the same parameters.
A purely-functional Haskell program would also be an example of a programmable declarative program.

For questions like this I also recommend the Mozart users mailing list and maybe the "Lambda the Ultimate" forum. At these places your questions may even be answered by the book authors.